# Gerar arquivo pdf a partir de um pdf object

Tags: python, pdf

Eu estou interessado em fazer um `crawler` para trabalhar com `pdf`, mas me bateu uma duvida aqui. 
Eu preciso baixar arquivos `pdf` de uma url em python, quando ela tem um `.pdf` é fácil e sem problemas, mas quando ela é um `objeto pdf` eu não consigo manipular, na verdade nem achei informação direito como isso funciona....
 
Ex: http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/servlet/INPDFViewer?jornal=529&pagina=1&data=13/11/2017&captchafield=firstAccess

Alguem sabe como posso baixer esse arquivo como um `pdf`?

Comment: Qual é a versão do python que você usa?

Answer (score 2):

### Requests

Para obter o PDF podemos usar uma biblioteca chamada `requests`, para instalar faça:

```
pip install requests
```

O código ficará assim:

```
import requests

# Url do PDF
url = "http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/servlet/INPDFViewer?jornal=529&pagina=1&data=13/11/2017&captchafield=firstAccess"

# Obtém o PDF do link, e guarda na memória
resp = requests.get(url)

# Salva o PDF
with open("diario.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: Cara vlw mesmo, não acredito que era simples assim

Comment: Por nada. Se achou a resposta útil basta votar em a favor, e se for a mais correta para você, marque como correta. Bem vindo ao SOpt!